# Java EE: Access current transaction information

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, weblogic, jta

I need to debug the Java EE Web Service transaction. I want to print the state, demarcation boundaries and commitment of the transaction inside my application logging. I want to make sure there isn't anything 2PC related going with the transaction and ensure it's initiated and flushed locally. How do I access the current transaction in the SEI and EJB classes to output the information about the current transaction? Is it also possible to register a callback for the transaction to log it's commitment? I'm using WebLogic 12c as the application server and Java EE API supplemented by some WebLogic specific API's to implement the asynchronous Web Services with JMS transport.

Comment: You can enable JTA debug flags on the server instance using folowing flags:   -Dweblogic.debug.DebugJTAPropagate=true  
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugJTAGateway=true  
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugJTAXA=true  
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugJTA2PC=true  
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugJTAJDBC=true

Comment: Could you please clarify the usage of "2PC" term? Do you want to prevent a shared transactional context *BETWEEN* multiple web services? Or multiple resources participating into the same transactional context *WITHIN* a single web service?

Comment: @Illya Kysil. I want to prevent the transaction context propagating across services (I'm calling one-way web-service using the JMS transport inside the EJB)

Comment: Any chance to get a feedback on the answer below? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53535107/1091731

Answer (score 0):

[Web Services Atomic Transaction (WS-AtomicTransaction)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec.html) and [Web Services Coordination (WS-Coordination)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wscoor-1.2-spec-cs-01/wstx-wscoor-1.2-spec-cs-01.html) are standard protocols which define transactional behaviour of Web Services.

Web Services participate in WS-AtomicTransaction transactions **ONLY** if explicitly configured to do so as described at [Enabling Web Services Atomic Transactions on Web Services](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-atomictransaction.htm#WSGET409).

Web Service does not participate in any WS-AtomicTransaction transaction if you configure SEI with

```
@weblogic.wsee.wstx.wsat.Transactional(
    Transactional.TransactionFlowType.NEVER
)
```

or provide equivalent deployment descriptor.